# Me devuelve 0 en un filter vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue2

Construi dos filters en vuejs para aplicarlos a dos propiedades pero a la hora de pintarlo me devuelve 0  he intentado varias maneras pero sigue igual.

Este es mi codigo

```
<template>
    <div class="center">
        <section id="content">
            <h1 class="subheader">Pelilculas</h1>

            <div class="mis-datos">
                {{ misDatos }}
                <br />
            <!-- aplicando varios filtros a una propiedad, falla: me devuelvo '0'-->
            {{ nombres | concatenaYear | mayusculas }}
            </div>

       
            <div class="favorita" v-if="favorita">
                La pelicula favorita es:
                <h2>{{ favorita.title }}</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="articles">

                <div v-for="pelicula in peliculasMayuscula">
                    <Pelicula :pelicula="pelicula" v-on:favorita="haLlegadoPeliculaFavorita"></Pelicula>
                </div>

            </div>

        </section>
        <Sidebar></Sidebar>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Pelicula from './Pelilcula.vue';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar.vue';
export default {
    name: 'Peliculas',
    components: {
        Pelicula,
        Sidebar
    },
    methods: {
        haLlegadoPeliculaFavorita(favorita) {
            this.favorita = favorita = favorita
        }
    },
    //filtros para aplicarle a cualquier propiedad 
    filters: {
        mayusculas(value) {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        },
        concatenaYear(value) {
            var fecha = new Date();
            return value + ' ' + fecha.getFullYear();
        }
    },
    //propiedad computada (modifica la propiedad original y generado una nueva)
    computed: {
        peliculasMayuscula() {
            var peliculaMod = this.peliculas;

            //recorre los títulos de la peliculas
            for (var i = 0; i < this.peliculas.length; i++) {
                //convierte en mayuscula el titulos de las peliculas
                peliculaMod[i].title = peliculaMod[i].title.toUpperCase();
            }
            return peliculaMod;
        },
        misDatos() {
            return this.nombres + ' ' + this.apellidos;
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            favorita: null,
            nombres: 'juan gabriel',
            apellidos: 'cuervo marulanda',
            peliculas: [
                { title: 'Batman vs supermas', year: 2017, image: 'https://as.com/ocio/imagenes/2016/03/22/cine/1458639537_473504_1458639748_noticia_grande.jpg' },
                { title: 'gran torino', year: 2015, image: 'https://www.iie.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/GRAN-TORINO.jpg' },
                { title: 'señor anillos', year: 2010, image: 'https://as01.epimg.net/meristation/imagenes/2022/10/10/noticias/1665397252_828059_1665397357_noticia_normal.jpg' }

            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `filters` no es un método, una propiedad computada... estamos de acuerdo?

Comment: No... en vue 2 existe algo llamado filtros para aplicar transformaciones a data, pero en vue 3 ya estan deprecados https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: @StefanoBozzi Hola pero viendo la documentación que me envías no veo nada diferente en lo que tengo